# xkeyval `boolkey` setting is persistent across macro calls: scope leak?

Tags: macros, key-value, xkeyval, scoping, default

I thought that `keyval` arguments to macros were supposed to be confined in their macro scope, but the following code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{xkeyval}

% Define a custom command option using `boolkey`
\makeatletter
\define@boolkey{myCommand}[]{option}[true]{} % one boolean option
\newcommand{\myCommand}[2][]{%
    \setkeys{myCommand}{#1}%
    \ifoption%
        \textbf{#2}%
    \else%
        #2%
    \fi%
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\myCommand{not bold} % default behaviour is not to bold

\myCommand[option]{bold} % explicitly set option to bold

\myCommand{not bold} % fail! default behaviour was expected!

\myCommand[option=false]{not bold} % workaround that makes the "default" concept useless

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: unexpected behaviour]

Why? Am I missing something?
Is there a way to get this default behaviour working regardless of previous calls to the macro?

Comment: There is no group in `\myCommand`. So the scope of the code in `\myCommand` is the same for all invocations in the example. You can add a group yourself with `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`.

Comment: @moewe Oh, so you mean it is my responsibility to close the scope of `\myCommand`. This works indeed, thanks :) Is an extra pair of `{}` equivalent to `\begingroup \endgroup`?

Comment: remember that this is a macro expansion language not a functional programming language, macro definitions are essentially just expanded inline and there is no scope associated with them.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That is true. When we get into concepts like "optional default keyworded arguments", it is easy to tend to forget XD

Comment: @iago-lito it's a "_uniquely interesting_" macro expansion language:-)  for your other question if being used for grouping `{}` is more or less the same as `\begingroup\endgroup` unless you are in math mode, but `{}` can be used for more things, eg delimiting arguments that `\begingroup` can not be used for, so it depends....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay, thanks! I'll go for `{}` in this case then :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Macro definitions don't add a level of grouping themselves, so everything you do in the macro code "leaks out" and just happens in the scope the macro is called in. The idea is that calling `\somemacro` defined with `\newcommand` is the same as pasting the contents of the code argument at that place (without the surrounding braces).

For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand*{\mygreen}[1]{%
  \color{green}#1}

\begin{document}
Not green

{\mygreen{this is green}

but so is this...}

again black
\end{document}
```

[image: The first and last line are black, the second and third line green.]

yields two lines of green text because `\mygreen` does not have scope restrictions that would prevent it from applying to the following line. The last line is outside the scope `\mygreen` was called in, so it is black again.

The simple solution is to add `\begingroup...\endgroup` to make your settings local to the macro call.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

% Define a custom command option using `boolkey`
\makeatletter
\define@boolkey{myCommand}[]{option}[true]{} % one boolean option
\newcommand{\myCommand}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
    \setkeys{myCommand}{#1}%
    \ifoption%
        \textbf{#2}%
    \else%
        #2%
    \fi%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\myCommand{not bold} % default behaviour is not to bold

\myCommand[option]{bold} % explicitly set option to bold

\myCommand{not bold} % fail! default behaviour was expected!

\myCommand[option=false]{not bold} % workaround that makes the "default" concept useless
\end{document}
```

[image: not bold, **bold**, not bold, not bold]

Comment: Interesting. So it is my responsibility to close my macro scope. Cheers :)

Comment: @iago-lito Pretty much. Although I would say that it would also be your responsibility to open and close a new scope if you want one. The default behaviour just does not change the scope at all.